# Refresh a div and reload a script

Tags: jquery, refresh, reload

So I would like to reload a div but I also need to recall a jquery script that is associated to it. Basically, I am embedding an external widget into my site. That external widget creates more js tags and css tags. But the new loaded div has no DOM attachment so the script and css doesn't apply to the newly loaded DOM.

Is there a way around this? The reason I refresh is because the widget is a feed of posts and I need it to update automatically as the widget itself doesn't do it.

Here is what I tried so far:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function removeCurator() {
        $('body').find('script[src$="https://cdn.curator.io/3.1/js/curator.min.js"]').remove();
        $('body').find('.crt-popup-wrapper').remove();
        $('head').find('link[href="https://cdn.curator.io/3.1/css/curator.css"]').remove();
        $('head').find('link[href="https://cdn.curator.io/published-css/b6d489d3-8a9d-4097-a1db-4a3435ae.css"]').remove();
        $('head').find('script[src$="https://cdn.curator.io/published/b6d489d3-8a9d-4097-a1db-4a3435ae.js"]').remove();
    }

    function loadCurator() {
        let i, e, d = document, s = "script";i = d.createElement("script");i.async = 1;
        i.src = "https://cdn.curator.io/published/b6d489d3-8a9d-4097-a1db-4a3435ae.js";
        e = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];e.parentNode.insertBefore(i, e);
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        loadCurator();

        setInterval(function () {
            $('#curator-feed').fadeOut();

            removeCurator();

            $('#social-media').load(document.URL +  ' #social-media');
            $('#social-media').on('load', loadCurator());
            $('#curator-feed').fadeIn(400);
        }, 7000);
    });
</script>
```

It actually loads the div and then shows the feed but it disappears after a second max...

Thank you for your help!

Comment: `setInterval`. You are recreating the `curator-feed` every 7 secs.

Comment: @user1496463 Yeah isn't that what I should do? Recreate the curator-feed every 7 seconds and reload the script so it recreates the feed?

Comment: `$('#curator-feed').fadeOut();` is causing everything to fade out. You take it out of the interval, and it shouldn't cause the flickering.